# SBMainWorkspace - The request was denied by service delegate

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I’m encountering a bug when launching an app on the simulator which is: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).

I know that there are some topic about this error, but any solution works for me.
 This is what I have already try:

- Clean Derived data + project
- Reset simulator
- Check empty environment variables (for all target + pod)
- Update Xcode
- Reinstall Xcode
- Restart the Mac (multiple time)
- Delete project & re clone it
- Check for Mach-O Type build settings is set to executable
- Try on different simulators (iPhone 15, 15 Pro & 15 Plus)
- Try on different iOS versions (16, 17 & 17.0.1)
- Desintegrate + reinstall pod
- Kill simulators, restart Xcode
- Many of the things mentioned above at the same time

Note that this bug only occurs on one specific project. I can run any other project on simulator normally.
The same project run also normally on other Mac.

Here’s my configuration:
Xcode 15.0.1 (15A507)
MacOS Sonoma 14.0
Mac mini M2

Here’s the full error log:

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x9ca3;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
The request to open "com.---------" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x9ca3;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. The process failed to launch.
Domain: FBProcessExit
Code: 64
Failure Reason: The process failed to launch.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = "launch-failed";
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Launch failed.
Domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Launch failed.
--
Launchd job spawn failed
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 111
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone16,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.0.1 (21A342)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 11035;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--
```

**Update**

I have try with another Xcode version (14.3.1) without success, the same error occur. Work perfectly on my personal phone..

I investigate log with this command:

```
xcrun simctl spawn booted log show --info --debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "CoreSimulatorBridge"'
```

I found a lot of strange log which said "Bootstraping failed" but it's to deep for me to understand. I'll give you more log details if you ask for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have been trying the above steps and formatting my complete system again for the past 24 hours.
What finally worked for me was the step I was trying to avoid.
Install rosetta running this command on the Terminal:
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Comment: I have see this step too but I was trying to avoid it too ahah. I can't try it now but I'll try next Monday. I'll tell you if it's works.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you give a little more context why rosetta might be the thing here?
Have you launched XCode unter rosetta?

Comment: Since any new project I was creating was working perfectly fine. I think this has to do either with some dependency library that was being used in that particular repo or some build setting set there.

Comment: I was facing same using Xcode 15, in my case is something specifically with cocoapods, projects without cocoapods were working fine.

And this solution also worked for me but I don't like it (using rosetta)

Comment: I didn't even notice any update in my mac. The error appeared out of nowhere. After `softwareupdate` now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

encounter the similar problem on actual device (iPhone, iPad), it turn out is because a accident added empty Environment Variable in Arguments tab of PRODUCT>SCHEME>EDIT SCHEME>Run (Xcode automatically add this variable even if you revert the code back to old commit...), after remove the empty environment variable, everything works again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hi had the same error my solution was to delete the source folder and clone it again.

Comment: Already try too, I forgot to mentioned it, I will update my post